# Fancy heading with letter and image with text

Tags: formatting

I'm trying to design the heading of a chapter by putting an image before text.
With beamer I was able to do this:

[image: text written on image]

with this code:

```
{\usebackgroundtemplate{%
 \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{imagenes/quijote2.jpeg}}
 \begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Don Quijote de la Mancha}
 \begin{center}
    \color{OliveGreen}      
    {\Huge
    {\calligra 
    ``ha de saber las matemáticas, porque a cada paso se le ofrecerá tener necesidad dellas''
    }}
\end{center}

\begin{flushright}
    {\color{teal} Cervantes}
\end{flushright}
\end{frame}}
```

and also I can generate this heading (the letter "A"):

[image: begining of chapter]

with this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{GoudyIn}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks=true}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\filright\color{Coral3}\fontsize{120}  {150}\selectfont}{\GoudyInfamily\thechapter}{0pt}{}

\chapter{}
\lipsum[21]

\chapter{}
\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

I would like to "combine" both images; that is, to have on the left upper corner a letter (A, B, C, ...) and besides it an image with some text. Is it possible?

Comment: I think Tikz will give you the best possibilities to do the job.

Comment: The answer provided by @jhor looks good. Please consider accepting it, if it works for you.

Comment: Yes, I woutd actually appreciate if this answer could be marked as accepted  ;-D

Answer (score 2):

I think that Tikz, though very efficient, is overkill in this situation.
I would suggest to use the package `eso-pic` which enables to put an image in the background. 
In this case it is enough to use the {} argument left empty in the OP MWE.

Here is a possible solution :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{GoudyIn}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]%
   {\filright\color{Coral3}\fontsize{120}{150}\selectfont}%
   {\GoudyInfamily\thechapter}{0pt}%
   {\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
      \AtPageCenter{ \raisebox{3em}{%
          \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{img}} }%
    }}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{}
  \lipsum[21]
\end{document}
```

which gives :

[image]

The position and size of the background image can be adjusted at will.
For example :

```
{\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
    \raisebox{0.5\paperheight}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{img}}%
}}
```

[image]

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you so much Jhor!